# C hash table multiple type input

Tags: c, hashtable

As a progressing C programmer, I have been working on a Hash table. The table works very well, is efficient(to an extent) and easy to implement, but one problem I have come across is that it only takes in **const char *** as a value type. I would like to implement a way to have the other data types without having to write out a method for each type. It's because I would have to make multiple structs to hold each data, then of course all the methods would need to be re-written to match those new structs and this will become very long and prone to error.

Is there an easier way to do this?

### Edit

For a little more info and an example, one of the methods is `void InsertInto(Hash_Table DataBase, const char * key, const char * value);` this works well because the key will always be a string name, but the value type can't be just char, I would also need it to be of int, float, and double, to make it efficient for my uses. And also as of right now, I have `struct element { struct element * next, char * key, char * value };` I realize also that this would need to become something different in order to hold all the types. An answer as an example, would be appreciated but is not completely necessary.

Comment: C doesn't have a one-type fits all. At most you can write your table to hold `void*` and supply callbacks that cast it back to the concrete type before hashing appropriately.

Comment: Use macros to simulate templates. And don't use void* unless you like debugging.

Comment: In a sad and unwanted way, would it just be easier to switch to C++ where I could do method overloading? Because as an added background, I am trying to create a programming language. C seems to be the best place for beginner lang devs, but C++ just be the better alternative?

Comment: Well, you would use templates. And yes it would probably be easier, but you would also learn less.

Comment: You should take what @2501 says on "learning less" using templates with a grain of salt. It's far less cut and dry than it appears, and there's much to learn about writing good templated containers as well.

Comment: I really think I could learn a lot from templating because, while I'm somewhat used to using Generics and <T>Templates in C#, I have only read about them in C++, I've never really had to work with them in C++. I still would like to keep the language that I'm buillding in C, meaning I will keep the hash table in C, but I think I'll look into a C++ implementation to find an alternate solution to my problem, until someone can lend me some knowledge about how I can accomplish it in C.

Comment: @Sora - There's an idiom called ["thin template"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Thin_Template). The idea is that you write the container as you would in C (with `void*` or whatnot), and use it in a thin template wrapper. That way you don't need user to specify the type information themselves, and can instead infer it before passing it to the almost pure C implementation.

Comment: And you can use the C preprocessor to generate a hash table implementation on the spot for concrete types. This kind of mimics C++ templates in a limited fashion.

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem. Just pass a void * with an associated size. Cast to unsigned char * for hashing.

Comment: It's *slightly* more involved then that. Type erasure means the casting cannot be done on the side of the hash table. It must accept callback for pretty much every operation that needs to know the concrete type in order to operate.

Comment: The hash table just supports insert, retrieve, delete. Calling code has to know what type we use for keys and objects, but it has to know that anyway.